# Как получать статус код динамически

Tags: golang, http

Есть вот такая строчка

```
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
```

Из которой я могу сделать вывод что статус это хэдер в http запросе/ответе. Отсюда вопрос: Как прочитать этот хэдер по аналогии с r.Method или r.Proto или r.Header.Get("User-Agent")

Мой сервер не делает запросов, но обрабатывает запросы поступающие извне. Как мне читать хэдер с кодом, с которым завершился http запрос к моему серверу.

```
func FillHTML(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templ, err := template.ParseFiles("../static/out.tmpl.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(status.Code(err), "parsing file error", err)
    }
    resp := ReqToGRPC(w, r)
    data := Data{
        Dat: resp,
    }
    templ.Execute(w, data)

    log.Println(r.Method, "----->", templ.Name()) //здесь еще должен быть код с котороым завершился запрос
}
```

Comment: Это вам где его нужно читать? На клиенте? Или на сервере? Если вы его сами и пишете, то зачем вам его читать на сервере из заголовков?

Comment: @RomanKonoval в том и дело. Я его сам не пишу. Просто строчку нашел из кторой можно сделать вывод что код это хэдер.
Получать коды я хочу на сервере и выводить в лог.

Comment: Используя net/http код будет в [Response.StatusCode](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http)

Comment: @umd `response.StatusCode`  то, что вам нужно

Comment: у меня нет response. Сервер не делает запросов. Он только обрабатывает входящие запросы @SeniorPomidor

Comment: @RomanKonoval у меня нет response. Сервер не делает запросов. Он только обрабатывает входящие запросы

Comment: Если я просто выведу r.Header то есть все заголовки кроме статуса((

Comment: @umd покажите кусок кода, который получает запрос, обрабатывает и передает дальше.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Done

Comment: @umd в данной функции вы можете только УКАЗАТЬ статус, но не читать. Если нужно читать, то лучше смотрите в сторону middleware для вашего роутера, который в конце напишет статус.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor то есть нужно писать http.NewServeMux и для него уже коды ловить и выводить:

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в middleware расписать каждый код нужно?

Comment: @umd пока реквест не завершен, узнать его статус нельзя будет. вот пример как я логгирую все API запросы.  https://pastebin.com/mJFhM60t

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а как завершить реквест, чтобы можно было получить код? Не понял совмем про middleware

Comment: @umd https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/7p35s4/how_do_i_get_the_response_status_for_my_middleware/

Comment: @umd это большая тема, лучше посмотрите на гугловские запросы на тему "golang middleware example"

Answer (score 0):

> Из которой я могу сделать вывод что статус это хэдер в http запросе/ответе

Вы делаете неправильный вывод. Код статуса (status code) - это выделенное поле в ответе. Он представляется числом из трёх цифр и передаётся в первой строке ответа. Он доступен клиенту как поле `StatusCode` структуры [`Response`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response)

Вам не нужно его читать. Вы этот код устанавливаете исходя из каких-то ваших соображений. Например, если запрос неверен, то вы устанавливаете статус `BadRequest`, если произошла ошибка обработки, то `InternalServerError` и так далее.

Comment: Ну получается, что мне нужно продумать и описать все статусы которые могут быть при запросе страницы и вернуть из в зависимости от ситуации?)

Comment: @umd ситуация гораздо проще чем кажется. Код 200 - успех, код 400 если в запросе найдена ошибка, код 404 если запрос к несуществующему объекту, код 500 если при обработке запроса что-то внутри сервера пошло не так.

Comment: Подглядел вариант middleware [здесь](https://gist.github.com/Boerworz/b683e46ae0761056a636). Адаптировал под свои нужды и все работает)